# Angularjs ng-bind is not working with regex?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Basically i am trying to style `|` delimited using Angularjs `ng-bind` but its not applying styles its adding `span` tag into string. what will be correct way using AngularJs to achieve this task ?

main.html

```
<li ng-repeat="message in event.data track by $index">
                        <span  class="messageMargin" ng-bind="messageTest">{{message.value}}</span>
 </li>
```

ctrl.js

```
var data = "[2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]|zds455|info|<n/a>|[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }" 

$scope.messageTest = data.replace(/\|/g, '<span class="pipe">|</span>');
```

main.css

```
.pipe {
    background: red;
    width: 1em;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ng-bind-html` instead, but remember to add `$sanitize` to module dependencies first.

When you use `ng-bind` angular ignores all html tags. Remember that using ng-bind-html may sometimes by unsafe (e.g. user can inject malicious code if he will have access to that variable)

Regex has nothing to do here. You just try to insert html tags which are not allowed in classical `ng-bind`.

Comment: it works but its crashing my browser i have live streaming of logs

Comment: there is no error in console my browser freeze can not perform any action

Comment: try to remove {{message.value}} from span. You shouldn't use it anyway when you use ng-bind.

Comment: what is assigned to event.data ? maybe you have too much data there